# Priest avoids turning into a vampire by exposing himself to sunlight

Tags: horror, identify-this-movie

**Genres**- horror,slasher

**Story**

- **Start**- The movie starts with a priest trying to kill two vampire girls but before he kills them, they cut him in the neck. Before turning into a bloodsucking vampire, the priest faces direct sunlight and it cures him.
- **Middle-** The priest continued his vampire hunting but one day, when he killed a vampire, a team of doctors(a girl and boy) get away with the body before the priest can fully kill him. It is later revealed that a wheelchair guy used this girl to get a dead vampire body for his experiment to get his legs back.
- **Climax -** They tortured the vampire in many ways, just giving him little blood to keep him alive and taking his blood for injections for testing purposes. However, during the experiments, the vampire get fully resurrected. Fights ensue in which one by one the whole group is made vampire or killed by the vampire or the priest. In the end only the girl and a funny guy, the priest and the vampire are left. The girl is turned into a vampire and the priest technique of facing sunlight to cure the girl failed because its too late.
- **End-** Vampire beats the priest and runs away with the girl (who is now a full vampire). The Priest teams up with the funny guy and the movie ends.

**Sequels-** Yes, not sure if it has prequel or not.

**Release year-** May be 90s

I want to know the movie name because I want to see its sequel.

Comment: I think it is _Dracula II: Ascension_ Check it out.
If it is then let me know I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @NishantKumar If you think you found the answer, feel free to post it without asking the OP if it is the correct answer. If it is a reasonable guess (regarding the descriptions in the question) and prooved properly, then it is a valueable answer, no matter if ultimately correct or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the movie described above is [Dracula II: Ascension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_II:_Ascension) made in 2003.

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0336325/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

> Horror following a group of medical students who come across the body of the world's most notorious vampire, Dracula (Stephen Billington). When a mysterious stranger appears and offers the students $30 million to harvest the body and steal its blood for auction, it's an offer they can't refuse. But as the lure of riches collides with unimaginable terror, the students also find themselves relentlessly pursued by a vampire killer from the Vatican.